# Open source home surveillance software

Tags: video-surveillance, home-automation

I have a Bosch home surveillance DVR system (I think the 5000 series) that came with the house that's connected to 8 cameras around the house

I want to have a home surveillance system that can at a minimum:

Record videos up to 30 days
Play back videos
Notify my mobile devices when there's movement detected
Now I was looking at open source options here and saw two main options:

ZoneMinder
Frigate
I tried out ZoneMinder and I'm surprised by just how janky it is. To start off there's three different ways of installing/trying it out:

A Docker version -> this doesn't seem to work even with the ports mapped, http://localhost/zm just 404s. Not sure if Apache is supposed to be running on the host machine, or inside the docker instance, but nothing seems to work here
Doing a docker build that builds a deb file -> deb file installs, but it isn't clear what got installed, there's no binaries or apps that show up
Finally, an Ubuntu specific package that ZoneMinder maintains. I'm running Focal so I tried the 18.04 version and surprisingly the instructions for setting up mysql does not work with mysql 8 (which is the version on my OS)
At this point, not sure if it's worth pursuing setting up ZoneMinder (I'm already hours in at this point and can't even get a UI loaded up) or looking at other options. Any tips on where I should go next would be great.

Thanks!